# How to load web page js after master page js script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

I have javascript code in a web page that needs to get loaded after js code in the master page, but .NET seems to want things the other way around. I have tried using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript, but the web page code still appears in the output stream before the master page script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try content placeholders for this.

In the master page:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
//master's javascript
</script>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="JsContent" runat="server" />
...
</head>
```

in the content web page:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="JsContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
//page's javascript
//this js block will appear after the master's one
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

RegisterClientScriptBlock , which inserts a script block at the top of the rendered page.

RegisterStartupScript , which inserts a script block at the end of the rendered page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hc29e2a.aspx#IncludingCustomClientScriptinASP.NETPages

Comment: If you read my original post, you will see that I have already tried this approach. What I needed was Andrei's answer about WHERE the code appeared in the HTML stream. His answer was spot on.

Comment: This will do what you want if you register the scripts with the corresponding register methods in the code-behind of your master page. The option is declarative vs programmatic :)